# Why does Ubuntu boot into a text prompt?

Tags: 12.04, windows, dual-boot

I successfully loaded Ubuntu 12.04 from CD to run along with Windows 7, then I clicked the install icon. It asked me which option I would like to proceed with, and I answered Ubuntu, in Windows 7. It did everything rather quickly, and restarted itself. Upon restarting itself it ejected the CD, and I thought everything was good to go.

It brought me to the Option to either load Ubuntu or Windows, I was thinking to myself, "wow, that was a lot easier than I thought." Windows 7 loaded fine after it checked the HDD.

However, when I went to load Ubuntu, it brings me to the loading screen and then stays there for a long period time. Finally it moves on as if it was going to load into the regular dashboard, but it loads into a DOS-looking thing.

And at the very time it says something like installation failed, it also says it could not find a file or something like that. If you need me to go back and get the full message and put it up here I will. Anyhow, if I put the CD in it loads fine.

Comment: Yes, please edit your answer with the exact error you receive. Please use the code tag "<$>" button in the editor to make it more readable.

Answer (score -1):

As you are new with Ubuntu, then I think Wubi is the best option for you. Just run your Ubuntu CD inside windows. If you auto play that CD, you'll find a option 'Install Inside Windows'. Just click on that option. Just fill the required fields, it will do the rest for you hopefully.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?